# Prove that there exists no ternary $(13, 3^{11},3)$ code

Tags: coding-theory

Is there a simple argument to show this? By the Singleton bound, we have $A_3(13,3) \leq 3^{11}$, but I know for a fact that $A_3(13,3) = 59049$ (see this link [https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/codes/ternary-1.html](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/codes/ternary-1.html)), so there should be a way to show that the first inequality is strict, that is, there exists no ternary $(13, 3^{11},3)$ code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [sphere packing bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_bound), or *Hamming bound*, we have
$$
A_3(13,3)\le \frac{3^{13}}{2^0+13\cdot 2^1}=59049.
$$